# Update person field (multiple selection) using JavaScript without PnP

Tags: javascript, rest, spfx, spfx-webparts, person-or-group

I am trying to create an SPFx web part using SharePoint 2016. When adding PnP to SharePoint 2016, it's giving me errors and not working like when I add it to a SharePoint online SPFx web part. How can I update a list item field to add the current user to it (or remove the current user from that field)?

I cannot find the API to do this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

How to update a person field using `spHttpClient`

A few things to note:

1. Before doing the actual update you must ensure the user Id of the user, this is what you will input as the field value.
2. You must add **Id** to your field name. If the field name is `Person`you should use `PersonId`in the update body.

```
private updatePeopleField(username: string, listname: string, itemid: string) {
    let client = this.props.context.spHttpClient;
    let clientconfig = SPHttpClient.configurations.v1;
    let options:ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      body: JSON.stringify({'logonName' : username})
    };
    client.post("/_api/web/ensureuser", clientconfig, options).then((res:SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      res.json().then(json => {
        return json.Id;
      }).then(userid => {
        let body= JSON.stringify({
          '__metadata': { 'type': `SP.Data.${listname}ListItem` },
        'PersonId': userid});

        let updateoptions = {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'odata-version': '',
            'IF-MATCH': '*',
            'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE'
            },
          body: body
        };
        client.post(`/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${listname}')/items('${itemid}')`, clientconfig , updateoptions)
          .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
            console.log('Item updated!');
          });
      });
    });
  }
```